# How to get different counts with one SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know this actual syntax is bogus, but it will help you understand what I am wanting. I need it in this format, because it is part of a much bigger query.

```sql
select location,
       count(*) as tot_proj where project_status='live',
       sum(fte_count) as tot_emp where project_status='live' and fte_count != 'NULL'
from table_name 
group by location
```

i want all this in one query...i tried this one

```sql
select count(*) as tot_proj,
       "location" ,
       sum(fte_count::float) as ft
 from insights_view iv2 
 where project_status = 'Live' and fte_count != 'NULL'
 group by "location"
```

but my tot_proj count is not matching...

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: @gudi . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: m using postgresql

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want the following syntax:

```
select location,
       count(*) filter(where project_status = 'live') as tot_proj ,
       sum(fte_count) filter(where project_status = 'live') as tot_emp 
from table_name 
group by location
```

This uses the standard `filter` clause to aggregate functions, which Postgres supports. You don't need to check if `fte_count` is `null`, since `sum()` ignores `null`values (and if you had to, you would need `is not null` rather than `!= 'NULL'`).

On the other hand if you are running MySQL and not Postgres:

```
select location,
       sum(project_status = 'live') as tot_proj ,
       sum(case when project_status = 'live' then fte_count end) as tot_emp 
from table_name 
group by location
```

Comment: I tried 2nd one but am getting error function sum(boolean) does not exist @GMB

Comment: @gudi: which database are you running, Postgres or MySQL?

Comment: m using mysql @GMB

Comment: @gudi: you wouldn't get this error in MySQL... Are you able to set up a DB Fiddle of some sort (like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/))?

Answer (score 1):

I would move the `'live'` comparison to a `where` clause.  Then, if you really mean `NULL` and not `'NULL'` you can just add up the values.  So:

```
select location, count(*) as tot_proj , sum(fte_count) as tot_emp 
from table_name 
where project_status = 'live'
group by location;
```

Note that `'NULL'` is a string.  It doesn't make sense to use `sum()` on a string, so I am guessing you really mean `NULL` the SQL keyword.  If so, that value is ignored by `sum()` and most other aggregation functions.

Also, the above will filter out any `location`s that have no "live" projects.  Because you propose a version with a `where` filter, I am guessing this is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
select location,
       sum(project_status='live') as tot_proj,
       sum(case when project_status='live' then fte_count end) as tot_emp 
from table_name 
group by location
```